How to get default /usr/share/nvim folder back?
I accidentally deleted the /usr/share/nvim folder. Now when I try to install lazyvim or nvchad, it shows the error:
/usr/share/nvim/systax/syntax.vim file not found


Find what package provides it - see How do I find the package that provides a file? - and reinstall that package

This question is similar to: How do I find the package that provides a file?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Just reinstall the neovim package:
sudo apt install --reinstall neovim

